# Query Wikipedia Software Infobox to Retrieve Current Version?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I would like to create a script to give me the current version of each software in a list of software. Wikipedia seems to do a good job of maintaining this information, and so I am trying to figure out how to query their API. For instance, it seems I get can get the current info by the call to API as such:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=QuickTime&prop=revisions&rvprop=content
```

This gives me the info for the page on QuickTime, but in the Infobox section, I am unable to find the "Stable Release" field.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to pull this off?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Wikipedia article you're referring to, you'll notice that to change the version, you should click the small “Edit” link near the version number.

That will take you to the page [Template:Latest stable software release/QuickTime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aLatest_stable_software_release/QuickTime), which actually contains information about the current version.

This is also indicated in the infobox as `| frequently_updated     = Yes`.